# can't access 'coordinates' member of geojson feature collection

Tags: angular, typescript, geojson

I have a GeoJSON feature collection in my Angular app that is an array of features, each containing a geometry object and properties object. Structure looks like this:

```
import { FeatureCollection, Feature } from 'geojson';

staticBreadcrumbs: GeoJSON.FeatureCollection<GeoJSON.Geometry>;

this.staticBreadcrumbs = {
    type : 'FeatureCollection',
    features: [
    {
        type: 'Feature',
        properties: {
            property1:  'property1',
            property2:  'property2'
        },
        geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [-117.14024305343628, 32.81294345855713]
        }
    },
    {
        type: 'Feature',
        properties: {
        ...
```

I'm trying to create a mapboxgl marker for each feature in the collection and need to get the coordinates from each GeoJSON object, the compiler is telling me that the coordinates aren't part of the feature. The specific error is: Property 'coordinates' does not exist on type 'Geometry'. Property 'coordinates' does not exist on type 'GeometryCollection'.

```
console.log('this.staticBreadcrumbs.features[0]', this.staticBreadcrumbs.features[0]);

var marker = new Marker(el)
    .setLngLat([
        this.staticBreadcrumbs.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0],
        this.staticBreadcrumbs.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1]
    ])
    .addTo(this.map);
```

My console.log displays

```
 this.staticBreadcrumbs.features[0]
 {type: "Feature", properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
 1.  geometry:
     1.  coordinates: Array(2)
         1.  0: -117.14024305343628
         2.  1: 32.81294345855713
         3.  length: 2
         4.  __proto__: Array(0)
     2.  type: "Point"
   2. __proto__: Object
2. properties: {deviceID: "CAP498", altitude: 401.6721913312, autonomous: 0, azimuth: 0, batteryStatusLabel: "Nominal", …}
3. type: "Feature"
4. __proto__: Object
```

The coordinates are exactly where I expect them to be, but I can't get to them. I have tried all sort of different ways to declare the Feature collection, but I can't find the right combination.

What do I need to do in order to access the coordinates?

Thanks.....

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> What do I need to do in order to access the coordinates?

#### Short Answer

Check that `geometry` is a `Point` before trying to access its `coordinates` property.

```
if (staticBreadcrumbs.features[0].geometry.type === 'Point') {

    var marker = new Marker(el)
        .setLngLat([
            this.staticBreadcrumbs.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0],
            this.staticBreadcrumbs.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1]
        ])
        .addTo(this.map);

}
```

#### Explanation

The problem you're experiencing happens because `Geometry` [is a union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types).

> A union type describes a value that can be one of several types. We use the vertical bar (`|`) to separate each type...

This is the `Geometry` union type definition:

```
export type Geometry = 
    Point |
    MultiPoint | 
    LineString | 
    MultiLineString | 
    Polygon | 
    MultiPolygon | 
    GeometryCollection;
```

As you can see, the `Geometry` type is a union of seven types. Unfortunately, not all of those types include the `coordinates` property.

> If we have a value that has a union type, we can only access members that are common to all types in the union.

That is why we are only able to access the `coordinates` property after we have narrowed the type.

#### Some Other Options

If you're using only `Point` types in your `FeatureCollection`, then use the `Point` type as the generic parameter:

```
let staticBreadcrumbs: FeatureCollection<Point>;
```

If you're using a variety of types in your `FeatureCollection`, then use a cast to tell the type checker that you're sure you have a `Point`:

```
(staticBreadcrumbs.features[0].geometry as Point).coordinates[0]
```

As shown in the **Short Answer**, instead of using a cast, you can use a conditional statement to narrow the type:

```
const geometry = staticBreadcrumbs.features[0].geometry;

if (geometry.type === 'Point') {
    const coordinates00 = geometry.coordinates[0];
    const coordinates01 = geometry.coordinates[1];
}
```

There is a short demo [of that last example here](https://github.com/shaunluttin/typescript-geojson-union-type-narrowing).

Comment: Thank you for that excellent explanation! I don't know that I ever would have figured that out by myself. But your explanation makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: Just changed my code and it now works as I first expected it to. Thanks again for your excellent explanation. Learned some great stuff about typescript.

Comment: This answer is useful enough that it applies to a wide range of Typescript reference narrowing situations. Kudos.

Comment: It's 2022 and this answer helped me, thanks